# Android License App showing Not-licensed?

Tags: android, google-play, android-lvl

I'am doing an app android license for paid application. In this app i gave base 64 public key & salt 20 random numbers according to my app details. My code is as follows:

initialized variables like this:

```
  private static final String BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY = "xxxxxx";
  private static final byte[] SALT = new byte[] {xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx};
  private LicenseChecker mChecker;
  private LicenseCheckerCallback mLicenseCheckerCallback;
```

in oncreate() doing like this:

```
   String deviceId = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);
   mLicenseCheckerCallback = new MyLicenseCheckerCallback();
   mChecker = new LicenseChecker(this, (Policy) new ServerManagedPolicy(this,
                   new AESObfuscator(SALT, getPackageName(), deviceId)),
                   BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY);
   mChecker.checkAccess(mLicenseCheckerCallback);
```

and My license checker callback function like this:

```
      private class MyLicenseCheckerCallback implements LicenseCheckerCallback {
           @Override
           public void allow(int result) {
                   if (isFinishing()) {
                           return;
                   }
           }

           @Override
           public void applicationError(int errorCode) {
                   if (isFinishing()) {
                           return;
                   }
           }
           @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
           @Override
           public void dontAllow(int result) {
                   if (isFinishing()) {
                           return;
                   }
                   showDialog(0);
           }
    }
```

from this I exported apk file and Stored as a draft in google play and tested with test accounts which are given in google play as test accounts and same account used in my device also. I tested many times this app everytime it shows only Not Licensed with dialogue. what is the problem?
plz help me..

Comment: Do you have more than gmail account registered on the google play of your mobile?

Comment: we have one publisher account and two testing accounts are given in google play. present i am testing with one test account of google play.which is added in my mobile.

Comment: I mean, in your mobile how many accounts did you set up ?

Comment: only one account is added

Comment: in your mobile, go under settings -> applications, choose the google play app and clear its data.  then try again

Comment: same result.. Always shows the alert dialog.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26852/discussion-between-nagarjunareddy-and-blackbelt)

Answer (score 2):

This error because of your public key, in the google play produces the different `Base64-encoded RSA public key` for every new application published from your google account. Check that key before creating your `apk` for your application.